# The lexical root of the perfect tense forms differs from the lexical root of the infinitive form

Tags: étymologie

Do the French have any verbs, whose perfect (passé) tense forms base on the lexical root, that differs from the lexical root of the infinitive form (by analogy with the Latin verb fero > tuli)?

Comment: This is called suppletion, and you can find it discussed on the Internet with examples. For example on [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppl%C3%A9tion). If you switch languages you can get different examples in different languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Aller* is the obvious example, since it alternates between three stems, with a different one in the present and in the perfect (I also include examples in the compound past which replaced the perfect more or less completely):

Je vais ↔ j'allai

Je vais ↔ je suis allé

*Être* maintains the Latin stem change between sum and fuī:

Je suis ↔ je fus

Je suis ↔ j'ai été

And *avoir*'s stem has attrited to nothing in the past participle and the perfect (it is preserved in writing as ⟨e⟩ but not pronounced), creating another alternation:

J'ai ↔ j'eus

J'ai ↔ j'ai eu

Answer (score 0):

That approach has not been adopted in the conjugation of the verb in French ; the lexical root perdures throughout the whole conjugation with in some cases a change in a  vowel  or a consonant but not on the basis of an opposition between types of tenses ;

(*for instance*)

- [faire](https://conjugaison.lemonde.fr/conjugaison/search?verb=faire) : je fais (présent), je ferai (futur)
- [peindre](https://conjugaison.lemonde.fr/conjugaison/search?verb=peindre) : je peins (présent), je peigne (subjonctif présent)

There is another particularity of the French verb, although it's true  for only a few verbs, and that's the occurrence of missing forms, as in  [this case](https://conjugaison.lemonde.fr/conjugaison/search?verb=paitre) (paitre).